# Pe file Vmp0 vmp1 section,

Tags: ida, anti-debugging, patch-reversing

I have a PE file with section vmp0 vmp1, possible protected with VMProtect.  I am using local debugger in IDA pro, the program will detect the debugger and pop-up an message box and quit , I used the break point on user32.MessageBoxW, the debugger will break, but I have hard time to find out which part of the disassembly code calling the function , would you please help me so that I can bypass what ever the program is checking.? I am struggling for a while.

Comment: At the beginning I can get the program running by bypassing isdebuggerpresent twice , but some how after working for a while the IDA can only break in the isdebuggerpresent once, the program can run in debugger within a virtual machine after I permanently patched kernel32

Comment: Use ScyllaHide with x64dbg.